# Жительница Тибета

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Как назвать жительницу Тибета? Если он — тибетец, то она кто? Тибетка?! Как-то не звучит, вроде бы (в отличие от "тибетец"). Тибетианка? Похоже на марсианку? Как правильно?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

**Тибетка**. Словари не против.
[Тибетка | academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/253934/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0)

А в чем сложность-то "тибетки"?

"Тибетианка" словарям не известна.